# How do I populate a popup window with values from a for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, popupwindow

I am building a user interface with javascript and some jquery that is populated by a for loop from an array of products and their individual details.  Once the products load with the abridged details, I want the user to be able to click on a 'details' button that will have make a pop up window appear showing the full details of the selected item.  I have everything working HOWEVER the window is populated by the last item created by the for loop, as opposed to those of the item selected.  I am pretty new to javascript and haven't been able to find any solutions that would fit this problem. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

```
document.body.onload = addElement;

function addElement () {
    for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        //Create elements for items and pop windows, and html for individual item details
        var prodDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var popDiv = document.createElement("div");
        // Add the rest of the html and looped data to variables


        var popUpWindow = "<div class='popup-content'>" + divName + divPrice + divBrand + rating + prodId + divLong + "</p><button class='close'>Close</button></div></div>";

        var blob = divImage + divName + divPrice + divBrand + divShort;


   //Account for null values
        if(items[i].brand == null) {
            if(items[i].salePrice == null) {
                var blob = divImage + divName + divPrice + divShort + dtlButton;
            } else {
                var blob = divImage + divName + divSale + divShort + dtlButton;
            }
        } else {
            if(items[i].salePrice == null) {
                var blob = divImage + divName + divPrice + divBrand + divShort + dtlButton;
            } else {
            var blob = divImage + divName + divSale + divBrand + divShort + dtlButton;
        }

        }

        //Add item info to HTML element
        prodDiv.innerHTML = blob;

        popDiv.innerHTML = popUpWindow;

        //Add class attributes
        prodDiv.setAttribute("class", "col-sm-4 col-lg-2 prodContent");
        popDiv.setAttribute("class", "popup-overlay");

        //Add new element to div
        var currentDiv = document.getElementById("allDiv");
        currentDiv.appendChild(prodDiv);
        currentDiv.appendChild(popDiv);

        //Appends an "active" class to .popup and .popup-content when 
                  the "Open" button is clicked
        $(".open").on("click", function(){
          $(".popup-overlay, .popup-content").addClass("active");
        });

        //Removes the "active" class to .popup and .popup-content when 
                 the "Close" button is clicked 
        $(".close, .popup-overlay").on("click", function(){
          $(".popup-overlay, .popup-content").removeClass("active");
});

    }};
```

Answer (score 0):

There're some problem.
You bind event in for loop, and event is bind for a class selector => all exists button will be binded again.

It's mean, if you have 10 item, first button will call 10 times click funtion.
You should move them outside for loop, or change selector.

And you must tell jquery exactly popup to show when you click a button

You can change like that:

1: add some thing to identify popup

```
var popUpWindow = "<div class='popup-content itemid-"+ yourItemId +"'>"
```

2: Then, bind to only right button

```
$(prodDiv).find(".open").on("click", function(e){
         //do smthing to show right div, 
         // $(".itemid-"+yourItemId ) .....
    });
```

and fix close button, too